# Usage of digital isolator

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, digital-logic, i2c, spi

Can this [ADuM1410](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADUM1410_1411_1412.pdf) be used to interface the SPI signals from this [Metering IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/Atmel-46003-SE-M90E32AS-Datasheet.pdf) to this [WFI32E01PC module](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC32MZ-W1-and-WFI32E01-Family-Data-Sheet-DS70005425.pdf)?

Comment: May I ask WHY you want to isolate the data lines? We use one of the ADUM series at work for a project where we need to ensure that MOPP2 for >2kV and man does this cause a lot of pain. So you should be 100% sure that you really need that separation.

Comment: @ChristianB., thank you for sharing your valuable experience with this IC. I am using the 3 phase metering IC and need to share that information to the WFI module. Since, the 3 phase metering IC is with refering to the RYB-Neutral and the WFI32 is with respect to the board digital ground reference, we need some isolator. Hope my approach is correct?

Comment: We don't know what approach you have to determine if it's correct. It depends where your board digital ground is referenced.

Comment: @Justme, could you explain on what you mean by, " depends where your board digital ground is referenced."

Comment: How you power your MCU board and if it has user touchable parts or external connectios defines if you need an isolator or can you keep the MCU connected directly to mains referenced measuring IC. But this is getting off-topic, as your question is if you can use a specific isolator.

Comment: Justme is right - sorry for carrying this off topic. Maybe you can ask another question to check the isolation diagram itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrically you'll be fine. You have to note that this digital isolator limits the data rate to 10 MHz, while SPI can go beyond that.

For SPI you have 3 *master-output* signals (MOSI, CLK, nCS) and 1 *slave-output* signal (MISO), so you'll have to use the ADuM1411 part instead.

[image]

<sub>Source: [Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADUM1410_1411_1412.pdf)</sub>

---

> 1. Why should this IC be used to interface the metering IC and the module? Why can't the metering IC SPI signals be directly interfaced with the module?

Both the PIC32 and the ATM90 can be powered with 3.3 V. So if both parts are on the same PCB and voltage domain I see no reason to isolate the SPI signals.

> 2. What's the difference between 1410 and 1411 part? It would be better if you could also add some information on the meaning of the ordering table guide on page 22 (like what is the meaning of the number of inputs on one side versus the number of inputs on the other side)

The 4 I/O paths (V<sub>A</sub>, V<sub>B</sub>, V<sub>C</sub>, V<sub>D</sub>) are uni-directional.

ADuM1410, ADuM1411 and ADuM1412 specify 4, 3 and 2 inputs on the V<sub>DD1</sub> side, respectively.

For SPI the slave has 3 inputs, and the master has 1 input. So you have to choose the option with 3/1 inputs, which is the ADuM1411.

I've highlighted the signal directions:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a couple of small queries. 1. Why should this IC be used to interface the metering IC and the module? Why can't the metering IC SPI signals be directly interfaced with the module? 2. What's the difference between 1410 and 1411 part? It would be better if you could also add some information on the meaning of the ordering table guide on page 22 (like what is the meaning of the number of inputs on one side versus the number of inputs on the other side)?

Comment: @Freshman First you asked if this isolator **can** be used. Now you ask why it can't be connected directly. It might be possible but might be unsafe. We don't know your system what is possible. But that is a completely different question. You might not need an isolator but you can use it. And which part you must use depends on which wires need to be isolated to which direction. Do you understand how SPI bus works?

Comment: @Freshman *What's the difference between 1410 and 1411 part?* <-- look at the red arrows.

Comment: @Justme,  I am using the 3 phase metering IC and need to share that information to the WFI module. Since, the 3 phase metering IC is with reference to the RYB-Neutral and the WFI32 reference is with respect to the board digital ground reference, we need some isolator, right? For that I thought we might need some isolator. Or do you suggest I connect the metering SPI output directly to the WFI module?

Comment: I am not suggesting anything until there is enough information to answer if the boards can be connected directly or through an isolator, but that was not the point of your question, you simply asked if an isolator can be used, and yes you likely can if you select a correct isolator for SPI bus and can power the mains referenced side and MCU side with isolated supplies.